# How do I make a control that can't contain other controls?

Tags: delphi, component-design

I'm designing a custom control, and every time I have it highlighted in the form designer and then pick another control from the control palette, the new one ends up inside my control, as if it were a TPanel or TGroupBox.  This isn't what I want, so how can I keep it from happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to remove the `csAcceptsControls` flag from the `ControlStyle` property, ideally directly in the constructor:

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csAcceptsControls];
  // more initialization stuff ...
end;
```